# Will mPCI cards work in a PCI slot?

Tags: motherboard, pci, pfsense

I have a really old computer that I'm turning into a pfsense router.  I'd like to add wireless support.  The pfsense [docs](http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Supported_Wireless_Cards) suggested I get a card like this [one](http://store.netgate.com/-P28C26.aspx).

Will this mPCI card work in my old motherboard's regular PCI slots?  Or do I require some sort of adapter like [this](http://dx.com/p/mini-pci-to-pci-adapter-with-antenna-9307)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The card is *electrically* compatible, but not *physically* compatible. You must get an adapter.